# UIKit restoration not calling viewControllerWithRestoreIdentifierPath on all VC

Tags: ios, state-restoration

## Overview of my app

-Throughout I use a navigation controller, it lies in a corresponding XIB MainWindow.xib. It is set as the root vc in the app delegate.

-CategoriesVC is a table vc, it is the top VC in the root vc.

-BooksCategoryVC (all books in a category) is another table vc that is pushed after selecting something from CategoriesVC

-BookScrollVC.m is a scroll vc that displays the text after selecting a book.

## Code description

1) In my app delegate I have set shouldSaveApplicationState and shouldRestoreApplicationState to return YES

2) CategoriesVC lies in the MainWindow XIB and I have set the restoration identifier in IB and in .m I have set the restorationClass to self and implemented the viewControllerWithRestoreIdentifierPath

3) BooksCategory has its own XIB and implemented the restoration protocol, pretty much same as

4) Same as 3) except the VC is instantiated in code. No XIB here.

## Flow

Start the application. Navigate all the way to the last VC (BookScrollVC).

When pressing Home Button in the simulator:

`encodeRestorableStateWithCoder`  is called in CategoriesVC and doesn't proceed to the other VCs. Shouldn't it go through all VC that have implemented the restoration protocol?

When restarting the app from Xcode, indeed only the `viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath` in the CategoriesVC is called.

**Please let me know if anything is unclear or you wish to see code**

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The app cannot restore if the restorationidentifier is not set. Altough I have set them in my custom initialisers it didn't seem to work. The solution was to set the restoration identifier on the next vc, before it was pushed.

I will have to dive into this and see if there's a better solution.